# How can I make my code only look at part of a string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that has part numbers in column c and then the line that they have ran on in the past (column A). I have a userform that looks like this,

[image]

the user enters the part number using preset comboboxes and then finishes the last 3 number in the textbox and also selects the line number they want to search.  I wrote a code that will search column A for the selected line then search in C for the part. **The problem is that the part numbers look like this** **02.N111.01** in the cells. The 02 is in combobox1, the N in combobox2 and the 111 in the textbox. How do I tell my code not to worry about the .01 at the end. I only want it to look for the **02.N111** portion.

Code:

```
Public iFirst As String 'From UserForm
Public iLetter As String 'From UserForm
Public iPart As String 'From UserForm
Public iLine As String 'From UserForm
Sub Start_UserForm()

UserForm.Show

End Sub

Sub FindPart()
Dim PartID As String

PartID = (iFirst & "." & iLetter & iPart)

i = 7

Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value > iLine

    If Cells(i, 1).Value = iLine Then
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = PartID Then
            MsgBox ("Cycle time for " & PartID & " on line " & iLine & " Found.")
            Cells(i, 1).Select
            Exit Sub
        Else

        End If
    Else
    End If
i = i + 1
Loop

MsgBox ("Cycle time for " & PartID & " on line " & iLine & " NOT found! New Cycle Time NEEDED!")

End Sub
```

Comment: Use instrrev to get the last instance of the . and then MID up to it, or left up to it.  Or a developer'y way, use dim s() as string:s()=split(strInputString,"."):redim preserve s(ubound(s)-1):strOutputString=join(s,".")

Comment: If the part numbers are of consistent length, the you can use the left function, e.g.: leftPart = Left(PartId, 7). If the size can vary, then you'll need to use the InStr function to find the second period (find the first one, and then start there to find the second one) and then use the Left function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
If Cells(i, 3).Value = PartID Then
```

with:

```
If Left(Cells(i, 3).Value, 7) = Left(PartID, 7) Then
```

Comment: @Duraholiday ............funny........... *"That counts 7 from the left*  **correct "**